# Why don't we reparametrize the Beta so its parameters represent number of heads and tails?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, beta-function

The Beta distribution with parameters $a$ and $b$ can be thought as the posterior distribution of the probability of heads when we start with a flat prior and observe $a-1$ heads and $b-1$ tails. And the parameters $a$ and $b$ can both be anything from $(0, \infty)$.

If we reparametrize it via: $a'=a-1$ and $b'=b-1$, we end up with a distribution where the parameters represent the number of heads and number of tails instead of having the $-1$'s tagged on. The only catch I can see here is that the parameters of this distribution can lie anywhere between $(-1, \infty)$ rather than $(0,\infty)$. But this seems a small price to pay for the more natural interpretation.

Am I missing anything? Is there any other reason we don't reparametrize the Beta so that its parameters represent the actual number of heads and tails observed?

Comment: I don't know the whole history of this, but my guess is that the current Beta distribution is parametrized the way it is because the normalizing constant is the Beta function, which is a classical special function. The definition of that goes back to Legendre. Connecting identities for moments and probabilities back to classical special function theory looks a lot nicer if you use the classical parametrization. The distributional identities for the Beta-Gamma algebra of random variables get messy if you change the definitions as well.

Comment: Why not let the normalizing constant diverge slightly from the distribution. Just say the normalizing constant of the Beta distribution with parameters $a$ and $b$ is the Beta function with parameters $a-1$ and $b-1$?

Comment: You can parametrize distributions however you prefer, of course. This parametrization makes the incredibly rich distributional identities of the Beta-Gamma algebra of random variables much cleaner. Statistics of the Beta itself are cleaner too. If $X\sim$Be$(a,b)$ what is $E[\ln(X)]$? What about $E[\ln(X)^2]?$ Or higher moments of the log? The Beta and Gamma distributions have an incredibly rich algebraic structure which is what makes exact computation possible. If you change the parametrization, those identities get much less pleasant to work with.

Comment: Just as an aside here, thinking about this a bit longer, the answer to your question is very likely that $\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$ is how we define the Gamma function. This choice leads to $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$. If the Gamma function were $\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}dt$, so that that was $n!$ instead, then things would line up cleaner for probability. But that's not how the Gamma function was defined and everything kind of flows from that. We want, for example $\frac{X}{X+Y}\sim$Beta$(\alpha,\beta)$ if $X\sim$Ga$(\alpha,1)$  and $Y\sim$Ga$(\beta,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Also putting in a very useful post expanding on the point about the Gamma: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20960/why-is-the-gamma-function-shifted-from-the-factorial-by-1. Is there any significance or interpretation to $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ being Beta?

Comment: Generalizations of that identity are how Dirichlet distributions, which are conjugate priors for categorical random variables, arise naturally. More generally, these types of algebraic identities are often lurking behind conjugate priors in Bayesian models. This is also part of a characterization of the gamma distribution known as Lukacs' Theorem: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $X+Y$ and $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ are independent if and only if $X \sim$Ga$(\alpha,\gamma)$ and $Y \sim$Ga$(\beta,\gamma)$ for some parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.